Error with laravel php so i cant run my project
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\oxorb\Documents\exam\ROV final project\fishpond-ayaWork/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\oxorb\Documents\exam\ROV final project\fishpond-ayaWork\artisan:18
i still new with coding and get this error when i tried run my friend project, i download it form gitlab. first i think that project doesnt have .env so i change env example to env but it didnt solve it then i think because composer error so i reinstall my composer but same it didnt solve. any solution?

In generally, you will face the error when you didn't install composer but try to run the PHP/Laravel project.  Please run composer install first and then try again.

you have to install composer in your computer and install dependencies by runing "composer install" in your laravel project

Your project folder name (ROV final project) may cause issues due to the spaces. Rename it to something like ROV_final_project or ROVfinalproject, as spaces in folder names can cause problems in PHP paths and CLI tools.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
